# How do I add a 1 second delay?

Tags: time, pygame, delay, wait

Hey I'm making this game and i need a 1 or more second delay?
Got any ideas?

heres where i need a delay in between tx3 = 1000 and cheesyx = 1000.

```
            if x < 300 and y < 300 and not duringfight:
                win.blit(cheesyt3, (tx3, ty3))
            if x < 250 and y < 250 and not duringfight:
                tx3 = 1000
                cheesyx = 1000
            if cheesyx == 1000:
                deathx -= 5
                if deathx == 600:
                    deathx += 5
                    deathmove = False
                    wmx = 1000
                    win.blit(deathtext, (dtext, 400))
                    if x > 400:
                        dtext = 1000
                        win.blit(deathhanpup, (deathx, deathy))
                        deathy = 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Since time.sleep doesnt work that well with pygame, you can use the time module to compare the current time with the last execution, and execute your code in a (event)loop only after more than a second has passed.

```
import time

last_execution = time.time()
if time.time() - last_execution > 1:
    last_execution = time.time
    execute_code_you_want()
```

Answer (score 0):

## **Pygame time**

In pygame, `time.sleep(1)` doesn't work well, so you could do `pygame.time.delay(1)`, that works fine.

Link: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.delay.